# Dictionary from list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a following list.

```
arr_lst = [(1, 34, 99), (2, 35, 40), (2, 36, 50), (2, 37, 10), (3, 37, 90), (3, 38, 8)]
```

I found dictionary keys, which is the first item in the tuple.

```
keys = {i[0] for i in arr_lst}
# output
# {1, 2, 3)
```

From there, I created a dictionary, whose values are the tuples from the first list if the first item in the tuple matches with the keys defined previously.

```
id_dict = dict()
for k in keys:
    id_dict[k] = [i for i in arr_lst if i[0] == k]
# output
# {1: [(1, 34, 99)], 2: [(2, 35, 40), (2, 36, 50), (2, 37, 10)], 3: [(3, 37, 90), (3, 38, 8)]}
```

Then I created a new list whose elements are tuples based on the dictionary values. The tuple whose third item is the highest in the dictionary values, gets appended to the list with the third item removed.

```
output_id_etak_id = []
for k, v in id_dict.items():
    m = max(v, key=lambda x: x[2])
    output_id_etak_id.append(m[:2])
# output
# [(1, 34), (2, 36), (3, 37)]
```

The code works and I get the desired output. However, I have a large dataset with over 800 000 elements in the first list, and it currently takes about 3 hours to run. I would like to find a way to make it faster.

Comment: The second step `for k in keys: id_dict[k] = [i for i in arr_lst if i[0] == k]` runs in quadratic time but you could get the same result in linear time if you just iterated through the tuples and used .append() on the list found in the dictionary at the right key. If the dictionary doesn't contain anything at that key, start by adding an empty list there.

Comment: In summary, from the list, your first item in the tuple is the key, and you want the max value of the third item in the tuple for each key?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Then shouldn't the answer be `{1: 99, 2: 50, 3: 90}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)(expects sorted input) to form groups based on the tuple 1st element and then select the first element of that group using `next`(suggested by [@tobias-k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k)).

***Note:*** In order to use `next` we need to sort the list using the comparison key `x[0],-x[-1]` so that the groups formed are in descending order.

```
from itertools import groupby

arr_lst = [(1, 34, 99), (2, 35, 40), (2, 36, 50), (2, 37, 10), (3, 37, 90), (3, 38, 8)]
arr_lst = sorted(arr_lst, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[-1]))
result = [
    next(group)[:2]
    for key, group in groupby(arr_lst, key=lambda x: x[0])
]
```

Comment: Sort by `key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[2])`, then you can just use `next(group)`. Also, a bit of explanation would be nice, in particular hat library `groupby` is from.

Comment: checked the timing on this. 3.76 µs ± 166 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each). Good result

Comment: @tobias_k where do i put the next(group). Will your suggestion make it faster?

Comment: @AndresKasekamp updated the answer to include `next`.

Comment: timing for the updated one... 2.98 µs ± 146 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Answer (score 0):

## Key = 1st element; Value = 2nd element of Max of 3rd element

If you want the 2nd element where the 3rd element has max value, then you can use this code:

```
arr_lst = [(1, 34, 99), (2, 35, 40), (2, 36, 50), (2, 37, 10), (3, 37, 90), (3, 38, 8)]
arr_dict = {}
arr_temp = {}
for arr in arr_lst:
    x = arr_temp.get(arr[0],-1)
    if arr[2] > x:
        arr_temp[arr[0]] = arr[2]
        arr_dict[arr[0]] = arr[1]

arr_relist = [(k,v) for k,v in arr_dict.items()]

print (arr_relist)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[(1, 34), (2, 36), (3, 37)]
```

The timing for this was:

```
For dictionary:

841 ns ± 21.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

Including recreating the list with tuples:

1.18 µs ± 41.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

## Key = 1st element; Value = Max of 3rd element

Based on the comment section, I am assuming that you want the first item in the tuple to be the key and the max of the 3rd item in the tuple to be the value for the key.

To do this, you need to iterate through the loop only once.

Your code will be:

```
arr_lst = [(1, 34, 99), (2, 35, 40), (2, 36, 50), (2, 37, 10), (3, 37, 90), (3, 38, 8)]
arr_dict = {}
for arr in arr_lst:
    x = arr_dict.get(arr[0],-1)
    if arr[2] > x: arr_dict[arr[0]] = arr[2]

print (arr_dict)
```

The output of this will be:

```
{1: 99, 2: 50, 3: 90}
```

I checked the timing on this:

```
792 ns ± 15.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: I think they want the first and second value where the _third_ value is highest.

Comment: just for your reference, ns = nanoseconds = 10^-9 and µs = microseconds = 10^-6

Comment: The output should be a list containing tuples. I believe converting the dictionary to that would be too time consuming?

Comment: Updated the code and also shared the timing

Comment: Frankly, using dictionary and using it for lookup is far more superior than iterating thru the lists many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to do this task

```
import itertools
arr_lst = [(1, 34, 99), (2, 35, 40), (2, 36, 50), (2, 37, 10), (3, 37, 90), (3, 38, 8)]

def max_2_1(arr):
    maxItem = next(arr)
    for item in arr:
        if item[2] > maxItem[2]:
            maxItem = item
    return maxItem[1]
    
arr_lst.sort(key = lambda kk: kk[0]) # important as groupby rely on this
aa = map( 
    lambda keygroup: [ keygroup[0], max_2_1( keygroup[1] )  ],
    itertools.groupby(arr_lst, key=lambda item: item[0])
)   
print(list(aa)) # [[1, 34], [2, 36], [3, 37]]
```